# Gunslinger's Dodge and Dropping Prone

Tags: pathfinder-1e

A gunslinger in my party was targeted by a ranged attack, and in response, he used a grit point to activate Gunslinger's Dodge to drop prone. The description for this action is as follows:

> Alternatively, the gunslinger can drop prone to gain a +4 bonus to AC against the triggering attack.

Does this +4 bonus refer to the bonus innate to the prone status, or is it an additional bonus that stacks with the standard prone bonus against ranged attacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically they reiterated the effects of being prone in the description of the ability. So it gives you the condition "Prone" which itself gives you +4 AC bonus against ranged attacks (and also -4 in melee).

Comment: To clarify, the +4 bonus referred to in Gunslinger's Dodge is simply reiterating the effects of being prone in this scenario, right?

Comment: "Alternatively, the gunslinger can drop prone **to** gain a +4 bonus to AC against the triggering attack." I think the *to* is what gives it away, instead of *and*, *also (gaining)* or similar.

Comment: @RichMahogany Yes exactly

Comment: You should modify your answer to make it clearer. The clarification shouldn't be in the comments of the accepted answer, it should be in the answer itself.